# How to solve the "TypeError: todo is undefined" in React?

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

So I'm trying to do a TODO app in React and it's throwing me an error that 'todo' is undefined.[here's what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkTlu.png). As you can see in line 7 I've declared the const{todo} = this.props and then call it on line 11. However if I delete line 11 the error is solved, but I can't add a task in my TODO app.

Comment: maybe you are not getting todo in this.props

Comment: It is because the one who is using this component is not passing todoo as props. Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're passing todo as a prop.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    const itemToPassAsProp = { text: 'Something cool'};

    render() {
        <div>
            <ObjetoTodo
                todo={itemToPassAsProp} // make sure that itemToPassAsProp is defined
                actualizarTodoFn={(todo) => { alert(todo.text); }} />
        </div>
    }

}

export default Parent;
```